# Mysql table to store age group ranges

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to storage age ranges in mysql table.

I want to know the best way to design such table

Example:

```
0-1 days
0-1 months
2-3 months
1-2 years
```

like this

I though of storing it as string, but that might be difficult to parse

Comment: The simplest is to store date of birth

Answer (score 0):

To allow the table to be dynamic would advise you that you save it as rows and enable the search:-

Now to group it based on the parent Id as below

```
0-1 days
0-1 months
2-3 months
1-2 years
```

now if anyone falls in the 30-day category the parent row will be 0-1 months and so on

I.e if ageCategoryParentId

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `age_range`;

CREATE TABLE `age_range` (
  `id` INT (50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ageCategoryName` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  `ageCategoryDescription` TEXT,
  `ageCategoryParentId` INT (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ageCategoryStatus` INT (5) NOT NULL,
  `userId` INT (50) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedAt` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `ageCategoryName` (`ageCategoryName`)
);
```

Comment: Well, it's not what I'd do.